# Can this Django query be improved?

Tags: python, django

Given a model structure like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Readingdate(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    date = models.DateField()
```

One book may have several `Readingdate`s.

How do I list books having at least one `Readingdate` within a specific year?

I can do this:

```
from_date = datetime.date(2010,1,1)
to_date = datetime.date(2010,12,31)

book_ids = Readingdate.objects\
            .filter(date__range=(from_date,to_date))\
            .values_list('book_id', flat=True)

books_read_2010 = Book.objects.filter(id__in=book_ids)
```

Is it possible to do this with **one** queryset, or is this the best way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Book.objects.filter(readingdate__date__year=2010)
```